# Substract cell value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So, I have two columns in workbook - name of material and quantity. So I need to find material by user's input, then get the quantity of material user wants to sale and make substraction. For example we have row:

```
tissue   15
```

We take input from user:

```
Material that should be soled:
tissue
How many:
12
```

Then programm needs to find tissue and quantity in this row and substract this and then update information in xls file like:

```
tissue  3
```

Here I tried code, that finds user's input material, but doesn't substract it

```
public void Order() {
        System.out.println("Material that should be soled: ");
        java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        String toFind = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many?: ");
        int quantity = in.nextInt();
    int searchColumn = 1;
        try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("solty.xls"));
             FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("solty.xls")) {

            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
           
            for (int r = sheet.getLastRowNum(); r >= 0; r--) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
                if (row != null) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
                        Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
                        String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        if (toFind.equals(value)) {
                            System.out.println("Text " + toFind + " found at " + cell.getAddress());
                            Cell cellInSearchColumn = row.getCell(searchColumn);
                            cellInSearchColumn.setCellValue(cellInSearchColumn.getNumericCellValue()-quantity);
                        }
                    }
                }
                workbook.write(fileout);


            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does you code ever get to this line and print the info to the console `System.out.println("Text " + toFind + " found at " + cell.getAddress());`?

Comment: @sorifiend yes, this code here works pretty good

Comment: Does a single cell contain both the name and value, for example, "tissue 12", or is "tissue" and "12" in separate columns? If they are in separate columns then you need to add `+1` to get the adjacent cell something like this `row.getCell(searchColumn+1);`. If the cell contains both the text and the number then you can't use `SearchColumn.getNumericCellValue()`, you need to get the string `cellInSearchColumn.getStringCellValue()` then extract both the text and the number `yourCellText.split(" ");`, and finally write the string and number back to the cell.

Comment: Read back out the cell after writing to it and see if the value actually changes `System.out.println(cellInSearchColumn.getStringCellValue());`, then you will know if your issue is related to how you are trying to set the data, or if your workbook is not being saved correctly. Note, `workbook.write(fileout);` should be outside the loop, move it below the `}` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @sorifien bro, it works now, you helped me a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I wish you all the best, now my coursework done and you literally saved my life!